# Using EasyVR shield 2.0 with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , is there any way i can use EasyVR shield 2.0 with ros? I have been planning to make a speech recognition using EasyVR and managed to generate code using easyvr commander and quick synthesis. This code is successfully working in arduino , and now , i need to find libraries or packages that can enable it to work in ros groovy.

Thanks in advance,
Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173336/using-easyvr-shield-2.0-with-ros/) by [manaXmizery](https://answers.ros.org/users/9931/manaxmizery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at Rosserial arduino. With this package you may publish or subscribe to topics to/from the arduino which would do the trick for you. This way you will be able to move your logic to the ros script and keep the arduino code as clean and implementation free as possible

---

Originally posted by [MarkGalea](https://answers.ros.org/users/22624/markgalea/) with karma: 36 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0